# How to add a load icon on google map while plotting markers

Tags: api, google-maps

I have used Google map v3 API to create Google map and to plot multiple markers on certain locations of the map. Since, there are plenty of marker to plot it takes a while to load. 
I want to display a loading icon while the map is loading and plotting the markers. Can any  suggest me how to do this....

Comment: Post your code so we can enhance it.

Comment: Click on below link to view my application: http://mapdev.srcc.lsu.edu/dragzoom1.html. As you click on this link it will open up a google map. If you hold the shift key the drag-zoom will get activated. Once the drag zoom is activated you can click and drag on any region in the map and map will plot markers on the dragged region. Make sure that you only drag a small region on the map because every region has many markers attached to it... I want to load the busy icon when the markers are being plotted.....

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads display the loader in the map div. Add an event listener (once) to the 'idle' event of the map that hides the loader.